# mysql query AND with OR not work

Tags: php, mysql

In my query I want to write where logic with And operation with OR . But my query not work.

```
select * 
from `data` 
where `city`='mycity' 
AND performDate='4' 
and (curtime() >= `valid_from` OR curtime() <= `valid_to`) 
and perform_type='ptype'
```

I think

```
(curtime() >= 
`valid_from` OR curtime() <= `valid_to`)
```

this logic not work

Comment: Question is not clear. What you are expecting and what is happening?

Comment: What is exactly not working? What is the result and the expected result?

Comment: The syntax is good, check if there is any matching record with the given condition.

Comment: Why not - `curtime() BETWEEN valid_from AND valid_to `

Comment: Consider setting up a SQL Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED ---

```
$time = curtime();
SELECT * FROM data WHERE city = 'mycity' AND performDate = '4' AND perform_type = 'ptype' AND ($time >= 'valid_from' OR $time <= 'valid to');
```

Source: http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php

Answer (score 0):

Change every **OR** to **AND**

```
select * 
from `data` 
where `city`='mycity' 
AND performDate='4' 
and (curtime() >= `valid_from` AND curtime() <= `valid_to`) 
and perform_type='ptype'
```